# What is the smile that occurs when a kid asks you for something you really know but you can't explain to them?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Say a kid reads a book contains a word "Fourier transform", then they ask their father who is a mathematician. He really understands what it is, but he sticks for finding words that his child can understand. All he can do is to have a small smile and say things like "you will know when you grow up" or "this is really hard to explain to you".

What are the words that better capture that smile?

Example: ________ly, he says to his curious child: "it is really hard for me to explain it to you. But if you really want to know that, don't give up. I'll always love you."

Comment: Please provide a sentence with a blank  (_____) where the requested word should go.

Comment: Knowing smile ?

Comment: I would call it a *perplexed smile* - the parent would like to be able to explain, but can't.

Comment: @user9825893y50932 is this good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a mixture of happiness and sadness behind the smile, then you can consider ***bittersweet***.

> : being at once bitter and sweet; especially : pleasant but including or marked by elements of suffering or regret
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bittersweet#h2)</sub>

However, if the feeling behind the smile is looking forward to the opportunity to actually provide the explanation, you could use ***wishful***.

> : expressive of a wish : hopeful
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wishful)</sub>

Or, you could try to split the difference with ***wistful***.

> : full of yearning or desire tinged with melancholy; also : inspiring such yearning
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wistful)</sub>

Comment: *wistful* comes close. Is there a combination between *wistful* and *knowing* smiles?

Comment: Perhaps *philosophical* or *contemplative*.  In a different direction, *sophisticated*.

Comment: Yes, I think *contemplative* is the word I'm looking for. Does it have a connotation of religiousness? I've never seen a smile that's *sophisticated*.

Comment: thanks. I think you should put these new words in the answer

Comment: Looking up the definition, it does seem to be related to religious contemplation. However, it is commonly used outside of that context. None of the recent examples cited by Merriam-Webster have anything to do with the religious association.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming the word 'wry' is fitting. With a more whimsical context perhaps 'bemused' as an alternative.

Comment: Why do you think that "wry" fits? It's used to describe expressions of disgust.

Comment: Laurel, the original sentence lacked context when I answered. As such I took it from the standpoint of a parent who was being asked about something they don't want the kid to know. Because of this, they'd be 'stuck' between the proverbial 'rock and a hard place' as how to respond without lying. I've never considered "wry" to be deceitful as more comparable to a 'knowing' look.

Comment: The question has not been edited. If there's not enough information in the question for a good answer, don't answer it. (BTW, a Fourier Transform is a type of mathematical function, so there's nothing to hide, but a child would most likely not understand any explanation, as the question alludes to.)

Comment: And use citations in answers, if you please.

Comment: "bemused" means "confused", not "amused".

Answer (score 0):

a smile of **happiness** and positive emotion:  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smile) aka the **Duchenne** smile.

Some smiles include a contraction of the muscles at the corner of the eyes, an action known as a "Duchenne smile", the smile of happiness.

In my research though I found that there are apparently 19 types of smiles (only six though denoting pleasure, sociability, happiness, joy or amusement)! [BBC](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20170407-why-all-smiles-are-not-the-same)  Who knew!

[image: smiles]

Comment: You said 19 smiles, but there are 12 here, and which one is the Duchenne smile?

Comment: @AzorAhai - i edited stock picture of smiles to a 'full, partial, and non duchenne' image.  The BBC citation had no pictures but describes all 19.

Comment: Can the Duchenne smile be called as "radiated smile"?

Comment: @Ooker  MW def:   : marked by or expressive of love, confidence, or happiness

    a radiant smile ... will research radiant and Duchenne

Comment: @Ooker  from a dental website:  and chances are that your new radiant smile will be of the Duchenne variety.

Answer (score 0):

"smiled pensively"

> pensive
>  adjective
>     Engaged in, involving, or reflecting deep
>   or serious thought.
>       ‘a pensive mood’
>
> ‘He asked the question as if he were serious, his face pensive as if he were really trying to figure it out.’
>   [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pensive)

I say "pensively" because the parent is trying to figure out how best to explain something to their child.

Or maybe stress that the question came as a surprise:

> "Unprepared, the father smiled pensively in his attempt to answer."